# Duas instalações do apache no mesmo Servidor

Tags: apache

Tenho um servidor windows com Bitnami (Somente com o Apache em funcionamento) e outro apache instalado de forma manual. Sendo que o Apache do Bitnami está para banco de dados PostgreSQL e o Apache instalado manual está para o MySQL.

Está funcionando normalmente, mas em portas diferentes. Bitnami na Porta 81 e o outro apache na porta 80. Sendo os dois apaches apontando para a mesma pasta onde os sistemas estão armazenados (D:\www).

Exemplo Bitnami (Porta 81):

> http://147.1.0.31:81/info.php

Exemplo do outro Apache (Porta 80):

> http://147.1.0.31/info.php

Existe alguma maneira de acessar a página sem digitar a porta, colocar algum tipo de alias para o endereço principal ou mesmo fazer redirecionamento de porta de maneira que quando digite o endereço completo de um sistema ele aporte para a porta correta?

Comment: O Apache possui o módulo "mod_proxy". Com esse módulo é possível fazer o que deseja.

Answer (score 1):

A única maneira de se fazer algo semelhante a um redirecionamento envolve usar as configurações de VirtualHost do apache e, baseado na url do pedido, fazer o redirecionamento para o Bitnami escutando na porta 81.

Seria necessário que o apache escutando na porta 80 fosse configurado com 2 VirtualHost, cada um com um ServerName próprio, como www.exemplo.com e www.exemplo.net.

Se o pedido for para www.exemplo.com, é servido o conteúdo desse apache normalmente.

Se o pedido for para www.exemplo.net, o VirtualHost correspondente do apache escutando na porta 80 retornará um redirect para que seja acessado www.exemplo.net:81, sendo redirecionado então pelo Bitnami.

É necessário a utilização de registros DNS para que funcione corretamente desta maneira.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi uma situação semelhante, só não era com apache.

Eu configurei um servidor (na verdade uma VM) HAProxy (http://www.haproxy.org/). Essa vm escuta a porta 80 e baseada na URL (ou em outros parâmetros que tu pode configurar) chama o serviço com a porta correta, deixando transparente para o usuário que chamou, ou seja, pra quem chamou a porta não aparece na URL.

Eu não sei te dizer se tem HAProxy para Windows, deve ter alguma solução semelhante. Ou tu pode configurar uma VM linux para atender os pedidos e então redirecionar para os teus apaches no Windows.

Não custa lembrar que não é recomendado (pelo menos até onde eu tenho conhecimento) utilizar PHP+Apache no Windows para produção. Se isso mudou, ignore este meu último comentário.